# Linear Charge distribution in thin (conduction) beam due to electric field

Tags: electric-fields, charge

I'm trying to figure out the linear charge density in a very, very thin conductive beam of 0 net charge due to an electric field generated by a source very, very far away.

[image]
[image]

Since the beam is conductive, there is no electric field inside it. Consistently for any chosen point distance $e$ from the start of the beam, there is no electric field.

$\displaystyle E + \int_0^e \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon} \cdot \frac{\rho(x)}{(x-e)^2} dx - \int_e^L \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon} \cdot \frac{\rho(x)}{(x-e)^2} dx = 0$

Since the electric field is constant, the heart of the problem can be simplified to solving 
$\displaystyle K = \int_0^{e^-} \frac{\rho(x)}{(x-e)^2} dx - \int_{e^+}^L \frac{\rho(x)}{(x-e)^2} dx$ where $K$ is a constant.

Analytical solutions are welcome..

Comment: You would have to consider the polarization, which depends on the type of the material, you would have to use this to calculate $\rho (x)$

Comment: I'm trying to get the answer for the simplest case; can polarization be ignored (I don't know what polarization is)?